# Options Menu stays open while running AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm rather new with Android, and with Java, for that matter, I apologize if the answer to my problem is a simple one.

The problem is that, once a certain Menu Item is selected, i need to run a rather long (2-3 seconds) task (involving HTTP requests, and as far as I know I need to execute said operation on a different thread than the main one) and then display part of the results gotten from the AsyncTask.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that the menu stays open the whole time the AsyncTask is being executed: I can't find a way of avoiding this.

I tried to sum up my problem with a shorter, but rather similar, example

Here's the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,1,Menu.NONE,"Text");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem mi) {
        try {
            String a = new AsyncTest ().execute().get();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the AsyncTask
    public class AsyncTest extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        long i;
        for (i=0;i<100000000;i++);
        return "Lol";
    }   
}
```

I tried using `closeOptionsMenu();` Right after onOptionsItemSelected, in order to close the Menu before the AsyncTask is executed, but it didn't work.

I didn't find much on the topic on google.

Answer (score 1):

get() is blocking. so basically you are getting the work down on the other thread, but you are essentially waiting on the main UI thread preventing the menu from closing.

try this instead:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem mi) {
     new AsyncTest () {

        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }.execute();
     return true;
   }
```